# How to properly use jQuery This?

Tags: jquery, this

I'm confused on how to use $(this) properly with jQuery. I have a list of prices and want to hide a sup tag if the price is "Free"

This is my HTML -

```
<li class="price">
  <h2><sup>$</sup><sub>Price</sub></h2>
</li>
```

This is my jQuery to hide 'sup'

```
if(
    $("h2:contains(Free)") 
){
    ('sup').css('display', 'none');
};
```

But I don't want to hide every price, I just want to target the ones in the list that are "Free".

I was thinking something like -

```
if(
    $(".price h2:contains(Free)") 
){
    $this.('sup').css('display', 'none');
};
```

How can I target using $(this) in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `$(this)`. You can do this all with a single selector to select the `<sup>` inside the matching `.price` elements.

```
$(".price:contains(Free) sup").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could target the `h2 sub:contains(Free)` and use `prev()` to target the `<sup>`

```js
$('.price h2 sub:contains(Free)').prev('sup').hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="price">
  <h2><sup>$</sup><sub>Price</sub></h2>
</li>
<li class="price">
  <h2><sup>$</sup><sub>Free</sub></h2>
</li>
<li class="price">
  <h2><sup>$</sup><sub>Price</sub></h2>
</li>



</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) and [children](https://api.jquery.com/children/) selectors in JQuery to modify elements on the same level or below level like this:

```
 $("h2:contains(Free)").children().css('display', 'none');
```